# Unable to Read/Write using pyserial on Linux (Xubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyserial

I have a proprietary device that is connected to my computer with a USB cable.

I have been unable to successfully read (or write, or both?) when running the code on my Xubuntu installation.

**Note:** The same logic works pretty much flawlessly on both **Windows** (tested on 7, 8 and 10) and **Mac** (tested on Yosemite and Mojave).

Here is the code I'm trying to run (hardcoded some values for simplicity):

```
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 500000, timeout = 0.03, write_timeout = 0.015)
ser.write(bytes([248, 40, 0]))
ser.flush()
reply = ser.read(40)
```

**Current behaviour**

The device is running some code that responds to the packets that it receives. In this initial packet, my Python code is requesting a full copy of the device's state, which it receives in a whopping 40 bytes array.

On Linux, the following is returned instead of the requested 40 bytes:
`[248, 13, 10, 40, 13, 10, 0, 13, 10]`

What I find interesting is that it returns the exact same bytes that I tried writing, with 13 and 10 in between them.

**Expected behaviour** 
On both Mac and Windows, something like this is returned (contents are not that important):

`[71, 89, 65, 32, 1, 4, 50, 0, 27, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 238, 1, 255, 255, 136, 1, 255, 255, 255, 255]`

The expected behaviour is the same as the behaviour on Mac and Windows.

**Extra info**

- Running on Python 3.5.
- I'm using the **exact same** USB device **and** cable.
- I've tried all ports on the computer.
- The code is exactly the same on all operating systems, with only the port name being different due to the nature of said OSs.
- The serial port is confirmed to be device I need (I print the name) and is confirmed to be **open** (I print out the serial object).
- I've played around with **timeouts** and **baudrates**, but to no avail.
- I've tried exchanging the read with a `if(ser.in_waiting): reply = ser.read()` but **nothing really changes**.
- I have verified that the device is on port `/dev/ttyACM0`.
- I have added permissions to that port after encountering a **OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0'** error.
- Permissions were added by using both `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyACM0` and `sudo usermod -aG dialout $USER` after reading some solutions on here.
- I have experimented with `time.sleep()`.
- **[EDIT] Tried out the suggestions given by [@michael-o](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55064963/10691720).** No luck.
- Some other SO questions I've researched and tried, in no particular order:

  - [Serial Ports Linux vs Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957705/serial-ports-linux-vs-windows)
  - [OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyACM0' - using pyserial from Python to Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858041/oserror-errno-13-permission-denied-dev-ttyacm0-using-pyserial-from-pyth)
  - [pySerial can write, but not read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49408849/pyserial-can-write-but-not-read)
  - [PySerial non-blocking read loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553543/pyserial-non-blocking-read-loop)

Any info/ideas will be greatly appreciated!

**[EDIT2]** The problem has become even weirder. Here's what I tried today:

- First, I programmed an Arduino on a Windows machine to constantly print a number and to blink the LED if it receives anything. Then I tested on the Linux machine and everything worked great.
- Then, we programmed our hardware to do the same - constantly print a number and blink the LED if it receives anything.
- Even though the logic is the same, it still fails to read or write anything to it. I even tried using GtkTerm to just inspect what is being communicated between the device and the computer. Nothing.
- However! Sending "X" to the device triggers a small custom-made terminal that has some built-in commands, like "S" for stress testing and such.
- The important command here is "E", which exits the terminal. If this is done (in GtkTerm), the device suddenly starts printing that number mentioned earlier. The intuition here was that on Linux (or at least in GtkTerm), "X" is sent to the device for whatever reason. So we tried exiting that custom terminal.
- This unfortunately didn't in Python. It still continues receiving the same packet as described before.
- So... we are stuck. But it seems like it is a firmware issue **bundled** with some weird quirks of the operating system. Will update if we ever figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolution:**

The OS sends "X" to the device 5-6 seconds after the initial connection.

This happens regardless of what applications are started. It does so in the background.

Our firmware was programmed such that "X" starts debug mode, which we use for testing the status of the hardware. It has to be exited before anything of value can be sent/received.

I am unsure as to **why** the system sends this character, or **whether** it happens only on that single installation, but it is a barebones computer with almost no additional software installed other than VS Code and Git.

**[FINAL UPDATE]**

The same issue was observed on other systems that were running Linux, more specifically, a Fedora instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it after rebooting the computer if you didn't it after adding a user into the group `dialout`.

Try to send additional information related to your device when connecting, such as `XON/XOFF`, `parity`, `stopbits` etc.

Add `# coding: utf-8` at the beginning of your script.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the suggestions. I tried all of them. 1. Restarting was done many many times, but I tried again anyways. No luck. 

2. `# coding: utf-8` didn't work. I also tried `# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-` from https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type.

3. It took me awhile to try all options for `XON/XOFF`, `parity` and `stopbits` but they all result in the same reply from the device.

Comment: @Ivan Try not to flush after writing, but adding a delay; also try `ser.read_all()` instead of `ser.read(40)`

Comment: None of these worked. I did some further testing (including writing/reading to an Arduino to validate that it's the device that's the problem). You can check out my edit if you're curious.